# Action bar in all uiviewcontrollers in iOs

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitoolbar

What's the best approach of creating an action bar (only once) in iOs that persists its position/size/content in all the UIViewControllers? 
Can I animate the UIViewController being pushed **without** animating the bar?

I was checking if it can be done with the **UIToolBar** or the **UINavigationController**. Am I on the right track?

Thanks in advance

Comment: both will work.  If you embed a ViewController in A UINavigationController, the push segue will embed the UINavigationBar to the next view.  If you have a UITAbBarController, you get different views for each UITabBarItem, but the UITAbBar remains.  Etc.., for a UITollBar.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Kindly check the comment that I put on Atif's answer for clarification :) @MinnesotaSteve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

**1-** Created a UIViewController in the story board that contains a UIView designed as an action bar and below it a **container**

**2-** I **embedded** this container to another UIViewController that will be the root view controller in this case

**3-** On **prepareForSegue**, I saved the UIViewController instance loaded inside the container

**4-** To switch between this UIViewController and the second one:

```
UIViewController *newController = ...
UIViewController *oldController = ...

[oldController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self addChildViewController:newController]; 

[self transitionFromViewController:oldController 
toViewController:newController 
duration:0.1
options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
animations:^(void) {
    oldController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0 - width, 0, width, height);
    newController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
} 
completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [newController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes thats the way to go. Also make use of a navigation hierarchy that will automatically give you a navigation bar (action bar). On a Tabbar you will have to create different navigation hierarchies.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I created a UINavigationController embed to a UIViewController and designed the bar as I wanted to. But, when pushing to another UIViewController, this bar changes to "< Back" which I don't want.. Any ideas? @AtifImran

Comment: Like I said it is available to you automatically if you're using a navigation controller. If you want to stick with a single navigation bar for all the view controllers you could extend the controllers to your base and set up your navigation bar there which will be the same for all.

Comment: But in this case when pushing the new uiviewcontroller, the bar will animate and re-appear on screen no? Can't it be done so that the bar remains still during this transition? @AtifImran

Comment: You could pushViewController with Animation:NO

Comment: mmmm so there's no apparent way to animate the uiviewcontroller without animating the bar?

Comment: Well you could still do that but why do you want to override the default way. If you're coming from Android this may be different to you but you should also keep the practices of the platform

Comment: Ok thanks a lot @Atif :).. Actually i started up developing on Android lol. I'll wait to accept this answer for this moment to see if there are some other propositions, if not, i'll definitely do!

Comment: No worries but keep in mind that UI is something that is specific for a platform and you should try to keep up with it until and unless there's a particular point in your app that needs it. This also will be a point during app rejection if you try too many things not practiced in the platform you're developing for.